# Unable to resume alarm after reboot android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

I need to resume an alarm after reboot. I am saving alarm time in **SharedPreferences** before reboot and after reboot i am setting an alarm with that time but it doesn't fire at all. 
Here is my code for the alarm in my Helpers class:

```
public static void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, long delay) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(AppGlobals.getContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AppGlobals.getContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)AppGlobals.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
    AppGlobals.putAlarmTime(futureInMillis);
    System.out.println("Alarm time before: " + futureInMillis);
}
```

I am using the above code for scheduling an alarm before reboot in another class and it works fine until a reboot.

Here is my AlarmReceiver class code:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Code for BootStateListener class:

```
public class BootStateListenerService extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, AppGlobals.getAlarmTime(), pendingIntent);
        System.out.println("Alarm time after reboot: " + AppGlobals.getAlarmTime());
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest Code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<application
    android:name=".utils.AppGlobals"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".services.LocationService" />
    <receiver android:name=".services.BootStateListenerService"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".receivers.AlarmReceiver" />
</application>
```

I am getting the same time after reboot in Logs which means my bootstatelistener class code is also working but it doesn't fire alarm at all.

Comment: your code looks ok to me. can you make sure that the boot receiver is calling properly and going inside onReceice()

Comment: Yes, i am seeing the logs of onReceive() after reboot.

Comment: can you make sure about your millis i.e AppGlobals.getAlarmTime()

Comment: Yes, they're same. I triple checked. I am printing alarm time before and after reboot and they're 100% same. I check every time before and after reboot.

Comment: I am not even getting the toast which i wrote in my Alarmreceiver class.

Comment: Also add next to BOOT_COMPLETED `<action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />`

Comment: And In which device are you testing  the app?

Comment: @bdevloper I have added that line as well and tested the app but it didn't worked. I have tested it on Moto X 2013 and 14, OnePlus 2, Android One device from General Mobile.

Comment: From where u r calling BootStateListenerService ?

Comment: @bdevloper I have added BootStateListenerService in the manifest and it works fine after reboot. I get logs inside onReceive method of my BootStateListenerService class.

Comment: did u solve your problem?

Comment: @bdevloper Nope, i am still struggling with my problem. Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

> Add this in your activity from u call alaram

```
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(Activity.this, BootStateListenerService .class);
    PackageManager pm = Activity.this.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: I am resetting the alarm after reboot. Do you want me to add those lines in onReceive() method of my BootStateListenerService class?

Comment: no. did u check SharedPreferences give correct time after reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code inside `onReceive()`

```
AlarmManager mgr=
    (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i=new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getService(ctxt, 0, i, 0);

mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                 AppGlobals.getAlarmTime() + 10000, 10000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it didn't worked as well. I don't know what's wrong. onReceive() is being called out after reboot and alarm time before and after reboot is same.